# Need to make a query more efficient

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, query-performance

I have a query which I need to make more efficient.

I am breaking it down into sections to see where the efficiency floors are, I currently have a few Nested Select statements, are these a performance problem?

Here is an example of one of them:

```
SELECT AgreementID,
       DueDate,
       UpdatedAmountDue AS AmountDue,
       COALESCE((SELECT SUM(UpdatedAmountDue)
                 FROM RepaymentBreakdown AS B
                 WHERE CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar, DueDate, 103), 103) <= 
                       CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar, R.DueDate, 103), 103)
                 AND B.AgreementID = R.AgreementID),0) AS DueTD,
       RN=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY R.AgreementID ORDER BY DueDate)
FROM RepaymentBreakdown AS R
```

Is there a more clean and efficient way of getting the data of DueTD?

Basically, for each line of a repayment schedule result, I want to get:

```
AgreementID,
DueDate,
AmountDue,
AmountDueToDate (DueTD)
RowNumber.
```

The table I am querying is structured as follows:

```
AgreementID (int), 
DueDate (datetime),
AmountDue (decimal(9,2)),
UpdatedAmountDue (decimal(9,2))*
```

**UpdatedAmountDue is always referenced as it is the moving figure, AmountDue is always fixed, as a reference value.*

Comment: It looks like you can find useful tips here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sqlserver/13744550#13744550

also, what dates do you have in your `DueDate` column? is (AgreementID , DueDate) unique?

Comment: Hi Roman, thanks for the Link, I will take a look at that... Re my data, `DueDate` contains dates formatted: > '2012-08-24 00:00:00.000', Agreement ID & Due Date are always unique as an agreement can only have 1 payment per day.

Comment: last question - is your DueDate sequential or it could have gaps?

Comment: There will be gaps in the dates, varying from 1 week up to 1 month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I think you could get performance boost just by removing convert, like this:

```
select
    AgreementID,
    DueDate,
    UpdatedAmountDue as AmountDue,
    (
        select sum(B.UpdatedAmountDue)
        from RepaymentBreakdown as B
        where B.DueDate <= R.DueDate and B.AgreementID = R.AgreementID
    ) as UpdatedAmountDue 
from RepaymentBreakdown AS R
```

The fastest way I know to calculate running total in SQL Server 2008 would be to use recursive CTE, see my answer here [Calculate a Running Total in SqlServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sqlserver). In your case the query would be smth like this:

```
create table #t (....., primary key (AgreementID, ord))

insert into #t (AgreementID, DueDate, UpdatedAmountDue, ord)
select AgreementID, DueDate, UpdatedAmountDue, row_number() over (partition by AgreementID, DueDate order by DueDate asc)

;with 
CTE_RunningTotal
as
(
    select T.ord, T.AgreementID, T.DueDate, T.UpdatedAmountDue as T.AmountDue, T.UpdatedAmountDue
    from #t as T
    where T.ord = 1
    union all
    select T.ord, T.AgreementID, T.DueDate, T.UpdatedAmountDue as T.AmountDue, T.UpdatedAmountDue + C.UpdatedAmountDue as UpdatedAmountDue
    from CTE_RunningTotal as C
        inner join #t as T on T.ord = C.ord + 1 and T.AgreementID = C.AgreementID
)
select AgreementID, DueDate, AmountDue, UpdatedAmountDue
from CTE_RunningTotal as C
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your conversion of the datetime to a date has several issues.

First, it is not guaranteed to always produce correct results depending on your servers language settings. If you need to do String manipulation on a datetime value always use CONVERT(,,126).

But more importantly, it prevents index usage. Instead use `CAST(DueDate AS DATE)` as the optimizer recognizes that conversion to be index-safe.

Afterwards you might want to add an index on AgreementId,DueDate and either `INCLUDE` UpdatedAmountDue or better make it clustered.

Assuming UpdatedAmountDue cannot be NULL, you can get rid of the COALESCE too, as the sum always includes the current row.

Comment: OK, so in terms of the nested Select, will it cause performance issues?

Comment: Most likely not. It is a single value correlated subquery and SQL Server should treat it as such. You could change in by using a `CROSS APPLY` instead but most likely you won't need to.